# Use a categorical argument to add one layer of list structure

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following nested list

```
x = {{1,2,a}, {3,4,a}, {8,11,b}, {12,3,a}, {4,3,b}, {3,2,c}}
```

I want to use the categorical variable `[a,b,c]` in order to group the above sublists (resulting in a list with "3 degrees of nestedness"). For the above example the goal is to obtain:

```
{ { {1,2},{3,4},{12,3} }, { {8,11},{4,3} }, {3,2} }
```

, where the first nested sublist is the group of sublists in `x` that contained the argument `a`, the second nested sublist is the group of sublists in `x` that contained the argument `b` and the third sublist is the group of sublists in `x` that contained the argument `c`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = {{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {8, 11, b}, {12, 3, a}, {4, 3, b}, {3, 2, c}};

f = Map[Most, GatherBy[#, Last], {2}] &;
(* or f = Most /@ # & /@ GatherBy[#, Last] & *)

f@x
(* {{{1,2},{3,4},{12,3}},{{8,11},{4,3}},{{3,2}}} *)
```

or

```
f2 = Map[Most, SplitBy[SortBy[#, Last], Last], {2}] &;
(* or f2 = Map[Most, SplitBy[#[[Ordering[Last /@ #]]], Last], {2}] &; *)

f2@x
(* {{{1,2},{3,4},{12,3}},{{8,11},{4,3}},{{3,2}}} *)
```

Note: Under this method, the ordering of the elements within each category may change (thanks: @Michael E2).

Version 10:

```
f3 = Values@GroupBy[#, Last->Most]&
f3@x
(*  {{{1,2},{3,4},{12,3}},{{8,11},{4,3}},{{3,2}}} *)
```

Comment: Note that the two methods are not strictly equivalent.  (E.g., try `x = {{3, 4, a}, {1, 2, a}, {8, 11, b}, {12, 3, a}, {4, 3, b}, {3, 2, c}}`, in which the elements are not ordered by the secondary criteria used by `SortBy`.)  (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2, good point. I updated with a note.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[l_List, cats_List] := Cases[l, p : {__, #} :> Most@p] & /@ cats
f[x, {a, b, c}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}, {{8, 11}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 2}}} *)
```

It will ignore the "categorical" variables not included:

```
f[x, {a, b}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}, {{8, 11}, {4, 3}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
groupCategorically[ll_List, keys_List] := 
 keys /. GroupBy[ll, Last] /. Thread[keys :> Sequence[]]
```

Example:

```
groupCategorically[{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {8, 11, b}, {12, 
   3, a}, {4, 3, b}, {3, 2, c}}, {a, b, c}]

(* Out[156]= {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}, {{8, 11}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 2}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DeleteCases[GatherBy[x, Last], _Symbol, -1]
(*{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}, {{8, 11}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 2}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {8, 11, b}, {12, 3, a}, {4, 3, b}, {3, 2, 
    c}};

(Last@# -> Most@#) & /@ x // Merge[#, List] & // Values // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

---

Result:

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}}, {{{8, 11}, {4, 3}}}, {{{3, 2}}}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `TakeList`:

```
x = {{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {8, 11, b}, {12, 3, a}, {4, 3, b}, {3, 2, c}};

Reverse[TakeList[Most /@ Sort[x, SameQ[Last[#1], Last[#2]] &], Range@Length@Variables@x]]

(*{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}, {{8, 11}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 2}}}*)
```

Thanks to @Syed for showing a more compact equivalent form:

```
TakeList[SortBy[x, Last], Count[x, #, 2] & /@ Variables[x]] // Map[Most, #, {2}] &

(*{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {12, 3}}, {{8, 11}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 2}}}*)
```

Comment: Simpler: `TakeList[SortBy[x, Last], Count[x, #, 2] & /@ Variables[x]] // 
 Map[Most, #, {2}] &`